# How to add two dropzone in one form

Tags: html, dropzone.js

My html code is

```
<form action="http://localhost:5000/fileUpload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="dropzone">
        <div class="fallback">
            <input  id="fileContent" name="Content" type="file" multiple />
    </div>
    <div class="dropzone">
        <div class="fallback">
            <input id="fileStyle" name="Style" type="file" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <input class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"></button>
</form>
```

and the `div` tag is does not inherit the drag and drop properties until and unless there is some value set to the `action` attribute.

basically i want two input to take two different files that is why i want two drag and drop boxes or inputs

Answer (score 0):

You must set some value to the `action` attribute. The `action` attribute specifies where to send the form-data when a `form` is submitted. So if you don't specify the action attribute, the dragged and dropped files definitely wouldn't find any destination after `submit` button is clicked.
If that is not your main problem you might wanna go through [this link](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2564-using-multiple-dropzones-and-file-inputs-with-a-single-plupload-instance.htm) about Plupload library for using multiple dropzones.

Comment: yes but i am specifying that action value in my outer form tag

Comment: In my case specifying it from outer form tag worked just fine!

Comment: did the form tag have `class="dropzone"`. Because in my case wanting to get two input fields that is why I need 2 dropzones.

Comment: Yes and I can take input  two different types of file in two dropzones.

Comment: You may read the documentation I referred in the answer, if I'm not getting you.